# Building a address book using a dictionary

Tags: python

I'm working on a tkinter address book program.  I'm looking into using dictionaries to build a address book program.  How can I input name and address info into a dictionary???  Can someone point me the right direction.

TIA,

Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

Just going to answer the only question that I see:

*How can I input name and address info into a dictionary???*

Borrowing from [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for dictionaries:

```
>>> AddressDictionary = {'jack': "Jack's Address", 'jane': "Jane's Address"} # Create dictionary with some names and addresses
>>> AddressDictionary['John'] = "John's Address" # Add new address for John
>>> AddressDictionary
{'jane': "Jane's Address", 'John': "John's Address", 'jack': "Jack's Address"}
>>> AddressDictionary['jack'] # Fetch Jack's address
"Jack's Address"
>>> del AddressDictionary['jack'] # Delete jack and his address from the dictionary
>>> AddressDictionary['Harry'] = "Harry's Address" # Add Harry and his address
>>> AddressDictionary
{'jane': "Jane's Address", 'John': "John's Address", 'Harry': "Harry's Address"}
>>> AddressDictionary.keys() # Fetch all the names (keys) in your address dictionary
['jane', 'John', 'Harry']
>>> 'John' in AddressDictionary  # Do you have John in your address book
True
```